# Grid in Footer - Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to implement button layout in a grid in my footer section.  But I am not sure why the buttons are not expanding correctly as per the documentation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    </script>
</head> 
<body> 
    <div class="ui-bar" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div class="ui-grid-a"> 
            <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="http://google.com" data-role="button" >Google</a></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="http://google.com" data-role="button" >Google</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my sample fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Axs6G/

Not sure why the buttons are not expanding correctly and taking 50% of each grid.  It remains only on the side.

Newbie Jquery Mobile developer here.

Comment: some CSS http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Axs6G/1/

Comment: oh...thought it would work the same even in the footer while looking at the documentation.  So there is special handling when grids are applied to both footer and header.  Thanks.

Comment: You mean _navbar_ widget? Buttons inside toolbars are `inline-block` displayed so they dont occupy available place.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .full-width-buttons .ui-btn {
    display: block;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar" data-position="fixed">
          <div class="ui-grid-a full-width-buttons">
                <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" data-role="button">Prev</a></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#" data-role="button">Next</a></div>    
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
Adding a brief explanation of what your answer's code does can be very helpful for others to understand